# How to ignore characters in a statement in R?

Tags: r, arrays, if-statement

so currently I have variable a, b, and c. I have a column 'v4' that is a binary variable based off of the 'v1' column. 1 (a,b, or c) 0 (not).

Example:

```
v1 v2 v3 v4
a  b  c  1
b  b  c  1
d  b  c  0
```

An issues I have with my data is that sometime they have years or other characters before the value. For example, I have instances of '2020 c'. This would be correct and I would want to capture this in column 'v4'. However, if these years come after it would be incorrect. Example, 'c 2020' would appear as a 0 in column 'v4'.

Example of how I want it to look:

```
v1     v2 v3 v4
a      b  c  1
b      b  c  1
d      b  c  0
c 2020 b  c  0
2020 c b  c  1
1990 c b  a  1
```

How could I made this work? Currently I am using

> df1$v4 <- as.integer(grepl("(a|b|c)$", df1$v1))

From this code, I am getting this result, which would be incorrect:

```
v1     v2 v3 v4
    a      b  c  1
    b      b  c  1
    d      b  c  0
    c 2020 b  c  1
    2020 c b  c  1
    1990 c b  a  1
```

this is good at capturing all instances, but I am not able to exclude the instances where the data is coming after the the variable I am trying to capture. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the problem is. The method you are currently using already gives the desired output of v4 from the input v1. Can you modify your example to include an instance of an entry that gives the wrong result?

Comment: @AllanCameron modified. Is that a little more clear?

Comment: Thank you, but that's not the result I'm getting with your example. Your own code works for me, giving df1$v4 as `c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)`

Comment: @AllanCameron Strange, another example I have is a-xyzrandomstuff, instead of just 'a' and a 1 is showing up in v4. I would need a 0 here.

Comment: that should still work. Let me show a reprex as an answer.

Comment: @OP. Give an example where your original command fails, or explain more clearly what the exclusions should be.

Comment: @MaxH. can you check my answer to see whether you get the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for the OP's test case. It is actually the method the OP is using, but seems to be producing the correct (and expected) results. I am posting this as an answer to allow the OP to test and find out where the problem lies.

```r
x <- c("a", "b", "d", "c 2020", "2020 c", "1990 c", "a-xyzrandomstuff")
as.integer(grepl("(a|b|c)$", x))
#> [1] 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

df1$v4 <- as.integer(grepl("(a|b|c)", df1$v1)) without $ could work

```
> yy <- c(letters[1:4], "2020 c", "c 2020", "d 2019", "2019 d")

> 

> as.integer(grepl("(a|b|c)", yy))

[1] 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0

> as.integer(grepl("(a|b|c)$", yy))

[1] 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: Can you explain what the $ is doing in this scenario and why removing it would help with this situation?

Comment: This will capture any string with an a, b or c in it. That's not what the OP wants.

Comment: $ match the end of a string, (a|b|c)$ indicates that a, b or c shoud be at the end.